# File.read on arduino Yun resulting in characters not in the file

Tags: arduino

When attempting to run an xml parser on my arduino yun, rather than the expected results of the contents of the xml file I get the following.

`Preparing to Parse
11:13:14.633 -> Ready to parse
11:13:14.633 -> ⸮ ⸮
⸮
⸮<)⸮! !"
11:13:14.666 -> ⸮⸮ff⸮⸮XZw⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮
11:13:19.923 -> Closing File`

For reference the snippet that is parsing is

        `it = xml.read();
        parser = String(empty + it);
        Serial.print(parser);`
in a loop of 
`while(xml.available())`
where it is a char, and empty is a string initialized as ""

and the expected output is

`<datavalues>
   <relay1state>1</relay1state>
   <relay2state>0</relay2state>
   <relay3state>0</relay3state>
   <relay4state>0</relay4state>
</datavalues>`

The Baud is matching at 9600 on the monitor and the sketch, so it shouldn't be that.

Comment: would be better on https://arduino.stackexchange.com/

Comment: What if you try a different (known good) XML file?  Do you get the same result?

Comment: The XML file shows to be good on other platforms, but I just tried replacing it with another, and I get essentially the same issue, result is ``
13:02:29.594 -> <)⸮! !"
13:02:29.594 -> ⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮U⸮
bdPQw⸮Q⸮⸮ `` from ``Testing
<relay1state>1</relay1state>
<relay2state>5</relay2state>
<relay3state>0</relay3state>
``